# Laravel Echo Authorizer

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redis, laravel-echo

im using Laravel 8 as api backend and react js in front.

im trying to build a websocket connection with react and laravel using laravel-echo-server, laravel-echo and redis.

the problem is im not using laravel guard auth ( *the auth process is written by my self for some reasons and handled with middlewares not auth:api guard* ) and so i can't using laravel guard for authenticate the user in private channels.
beacuse of that im looking for other ways to authenticate users in private channels without laravel guard.
i tried laravel-echo authorizer :

```
window.io = socketio;
window.Echo = new Echo({
       authorizer: (channel, options) => {
             return {
                    authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
                          axios.post('/api/auth/custom', {
                               socket_id: socketId,
                               channel_name: channel.name
                           }).then(response => {
                               callback(false, response.data);
                           }).catch(error => {
                               callback(true, error);
                     });
                }
           };
      },
      broadcaster: 'socket.io',
      host: `${host}:${port}`,
      transports: ['websocket'],
});
```

but nothing happend. actually no request is sent to the `'/api/auth/custom'`

at the end, Channels are working but Private Channels need authentication...

any solutions ?